# Get Column Index based on Value rather than Column Label

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Say I have the following Dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"],["g", "h", "i"]])
```

How do I get the column index of "c" in row 0?

I know there are ways to get the column index if there are column labels, but I can't find ways to return the column index just based on the cell value, if searching a particular row.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
df[df[df.eq("c").any(1)].T.eq("c").any(1)].index[0]

2
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know what wizardry is going on here, but this works neatly!

Answer (score 0):

**Here's one way:**

You can create a extra dataframe that check each cell value in your original dataframe to locate the string inside each cell. Here you would like to find `c` which can be mapped as follow:

```
check_df = df.applymap(lambda in_each_cell_value: str(in_each_cell_value).find("c") >= 0)
```

The check_df returns the boolean values and locates the string in the cell.
[image]

From the above 'check_df' you can extract and keep the column where the cell was found:

```
[column for column, count in check_df.sum().to_dict().items() 
     if count > 0]
```

**Complete code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"],["g", "h", "i"]])
check_df = df.applymap(lambda in_each_cell_value: str(in_each_cell_value).find("c") >= 0)
ind = [column for column, count in check_df.sum().to_dict().items() 
     if count > 0]
```

**Outputs:**

```
ind[0]
2
```